# How can I avoid passing an empty multi-select parameter to a report

Tags: reporting-services

I have added a text box to my SSRS report that opens another SSRS report, passing a multi-select parameter in the process.

What can I put in the text boxes' Action Omit expression for that parameter to prevent that parameter from being passed when it is empty (i.e. nothing is selected)?
[image]

Comment: The parameter will always have some state, even it it is null. How does the main report handle the parameter when it's "empty"? What is the drill thru report expecting? If you really have to you can check the selected values count with `Parameters!myParameter.Count` and then pass a different value. Personally I'd make sure the drill thru report can handle null parameter values

Comment: The main report doesn't use the param. It's only there to hold the value of a param in a calling report, for the sole purpose of handing it back to that calling report when it's navigated back to. e.g. The user starts with Report A, sets a parameter on that report, but then navigates to B, which doesn't use that parameter.  I set up B to accept that parameter so that it can be handed back to A when the user is done with B and drills back to A. The problem arises when the user starts at B - the parameter never gets an initial value. In this case, I want A's parameter to fill with defaults.